# {{#each loop}} not working. What would be the right way to get it going

Tags: ember.js

I am following an example at "emberjs.com" which isn't going too well. I have a "GuestController" and "GuestView" within my application. I would like to use the "{{#view}} & {{#each}} to output an object called "guests" from the "GuestView". I am following this online example:

http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_displaying-a-list-of-items

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exciter/MjA5A/8/

Here is the code:

APP CODE:

```
$(function(){

    App = Ember.Application.create({
        ready: function(){
            //alert("APP INIT");
        }
    });

    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: "application",
        classNames: ['']
    });

    App.GuestController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.GuestView = Ember.View.extend({

        guests: [{name:"The Doctor" },
                 {name:"The Scientist" },
                 {name:"The Maestro"}]

    });

    App.initialize();
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

    {{#each App.GuestController}}
        {{#view App.GuestView}}
            {{guests}}
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Also you forgot to load HandlebarJS in the resources panel which should be loaded before EmberJS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, we use `{{each}}` block helper to iterate over an array of items, now when you say `{{#each GuestController}}` the controller should be of type `Ember.ArrayController`, and the `{{#each GuestController}}` looks for the content property inside the GuestController which will be used to iterate over, As per the example I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MjA5A/9/) is what you are trying to implement...
Instead if you want to iterate over an Array inside a view check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MjA5A/10/)

Comment: Thank you @unspecified. This is absolutely fantastic. Would you happened to have a fiddle demoing an array instead of variable, plz.

Comment: Sorry, did not get the "an array instead of variable" thing that you said, The fiddle has array iterations right ?